# error: struct has no member named X

Tags: c, struct, tree, binary-tree

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 struct treeNode
 {
    *char word;
    int NumberCnt; 
    struct treeNode *rightPTR, *leftPTR; 

 };
 typedef struct treeNode node;

  node *rootPTR = NULL;

 void freeTree(node *currPTR)
 {
     if (currPTR!= NULL)
    {
        freeTree(currPTR -> leftPTR);
        free(currPTR);
        freeTree(currPTR -> rightPTR);
    }
 }

void printTree(node *currPTR)
{
    if (currPTR != NULL)
        {
            printTree(currPTR ->leftPTR);   
            printf("%d\n", currPTR->word);
            printTree(currPTR ->rightPTR);  
        }
}



int insertNode (char* input)
{

    node *tempPTR = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tempPTR -> word = input;
    tempPTR -> NumberCnt=0;
    tempPTR -> leftPTR = NULL;
    tempPTR -> rightPTR = NULL;

    if (rootPTR == NULL)
    {   
        rootPTR = tempPTR;
        rootPTR -> NumberCnt++;
    }
     else 
    {
        int comp;
        node *currPTR = rootPTR;
        node *prevPTR = NULL;

            while (currPTR != NULL)
            {
                comp = strcmp(input, (currPTR->word));
                if (comp = 0)
                {
                    printf ("Entry already exists");
                    return 1;   
                }
                else if (comp < 0)
                {
                    prevPTR = currPTR;
                    currPTR = currPTR->leftPTR;
                }
                else if (comp > 0)
                {
                    prevPTR = currPTR;
                    currPTR = currPTR->rightPTR;
                }

            }

        comp = strcmp(input, (prevPTR ->word));
        if (comp < 0)
        {
            prevPTR->leftPTR = tempPTR;

        }

        else if (comp > 0)
        {
            prevPTR->rightPTR = tempPTR;

        }

        return 0;   
    }

    return 2;
}

int search(char* input) 
{
     if (input == rootPTR ->data)
    {
        printf("Node found %d\n", rootPTR->data);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (input < rootPTR ->data)
            {

                node *currPTR = rootPTR->leftPTR;

                while (currPTR != NULL)
                 {
                    if (input == currPTR->data)
                    {
                        printf("Node found %d\n", currPTR->data);
                         return 0;
                     }
                    else if (input < currPTR->data)
                    {
                        currPTR = (currPTR -> leftPTR); 
                    }
                    else if (input > currPTR->data)
                    {
                        currPTR = (currPTR -> rightPTR);
                     } 
                }
                printf ("Node not in tree\n");
                return 1;
            }

             if (input > rootPTR ->data)
            {

                node *currPTR = rootPTR->rightPTR;

                while (currPTR != NULL)
                {

                    if (input == currPTR->data)
                    {
                        printf ("Node found %d\n", currPTR->data);
                        return 0;
                    }

                    else if (input < currPTR->data)
                    {
                        currPTR = (currPTR -> leftPTR); 
                    } 

                    else if (input > currPTR->data)
                    {
                        currPTR = (currPTR ->rightPTR);
                    }
                }
                printf ("Node not in tree\n");
                return 1;
            }

    }

return 2;
}

void fixWord(char* buff)
{
    char* unfixed = buff;
    char* fixed = buff;

    while (*unfixed)
    {

            if (isalpha(*unfixed))
        {
            *fixed=tolower(*unfixed);
                *fixed++;

        }   
            *unfixed++;


    }
    *fixed=0;

}


int main()
{   
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buff [100];
  //ptr_file = fopen ("sherlock.txt", "r");
    ptr_file = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        printf("File read error");


        while(fscanf(ptr_file, "%s ", buff ) != EOF)
        {
            int comparison = strcmp(buff, "endoffile");
            if (comparison == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

             fixWord(buff);
             insert(buff);
        }

    fclose(ptr_file);

}
```

I have this code which is a binary tree which reads in text from a file and then adds it to a binary tree. I have a struct to represent a new node which takes in a string and a integer which increments to show word count. I originally had this tree set up to take in integers to test the tree functionality and it worked just fine, however since updating my struct to take in the string and the incremented integer the compiler is complaining the struct does not longer contains any of the members of the struct. I have no idea why this happening.

Comment: "*char word;" should be "char *word."

Comment: `rightptr` is not the same thing as `rightPTR`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about simple typoes, unlikely to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: Sorry this was a bad question been working since 8am, thanks you sorted my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the *first* error message of the compiler. It should complain about the `*char` in line 6, which should be `char *`.

By the way: always copy and paste error messages, so that we get the original messages.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a member `data` like `rootPTR ->data` at several places in the `search` function but the `struct treeNode` has no member called `data`.